# How do I make IntelliJ IDEA automatically extract a dependency to the artifact jar?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, netbeans, dependencies

Let's say I'm adding the following dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.ini4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>ini4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I can now use the Ini class as expected, but if I try to build the jar and run it, it will give me a "noclassdeffounderror" error. When I check the content of the jar, it does not contain org/ini4j.

I was able to fix this by going into File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts

[image: Extracting into Output Root]
[image: After extracting into Output Root]

If I want to add another dependency, I'll have to do this every time, which is quite tedious (I didn't need to do this on NetBeans). I then tried to use the following plugins (which I used on NetBeans) to have Maven create a jar with dependencies automatically.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>main.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

On NetBeans, this automatically adds all dependencies to the jar file, but it doesn't do anything on IntelliJ IDEA. I have no idea what I'm doing anymore; nothing works. How can I make IntelliJ IDEA automatically extract a dependency into the output root?

Answer (score 0):

Dose your intellij use the same version on maven that your Netbeans uses? if it checks fine, try another plugin for making a fat jar such as the folowing:

```
 <build>
<plugins>
  <!-- any other plugins -->
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Both my NetBeans project and the IntelliJ project are using version 4.0.0. I tried the plugin you suggested but the dependencies are still missing unless I manually add it myself. Thank you for the help anyways though!